# SMTNodeData in BatchModeSteering

Tags: finite-element-method, acegen

Does anyone know wether it is at all possible to read/modify node data or element data within the batch mode steering procedure of AceFEM?

I'm looking for something like:

```
htdata = SMT -> NodeData[1, "ht"]
```

to make use of the numbers (e.g. double in C++) or

```
SMT -> NodeData[1, "Data", 1]
```

to even write doubles into the data fields.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

List of input parameters of steering function contains pointers to all data structures. Elements, nodes, etc. C definition of data structures is available in `sms.h` header file.

```cpp
DLLEXPORT int 
  Simulation(SMTStructure* SMT, 
             ElementSpec** ElemSpecs, 
             ElementData** Elements, 
             NodeSpec** NodeSpecs, 
             NodeData** Nodes, 
             int* IData, 
             double* RData)
```

You can directly change most of the simulation data. E.g.

```
Nodes[0] -> X[0] = 5;
```

would set first coordinate in first node to 5 or

```
Elements[1000] -> Nodes[5]
```

gives 6-th node in 1001-th element.